# How to get the split string i have used to split the string

Tags: php

I have a String as follows

"2012-06-29 Some text 2012-06-30 Some text .."
I m splitting the above text in php using split(regex of the date), but i need to get that date too. I wanted to get the split string i have used to split the string. I need Split String , the date and the string that following in separate variables to process.

Like

> ```
>    2012-06-29 App Started
>    2012-06-30 Login Event
> ```

How can i get this in php

Comment: You can split by " ", but limit the number of splits to 1.

Comment: Before splitting you can create an array of these dates using preg_match and then merge with splited one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somthingl like?

```
preg_match_all("#(?<date>[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}) (?<text>[^0-9]+)#", $text, $matches)
```

Exemple code

```
        $text = "2012-12-25 xmas 1984-06-01 Puggans birhday 2012-07-28 today";

        preg_match_all("#(?<date>[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}) (?<text>[^0-9]+)#", $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

        foreach($matches as $current_match)
        {
                echo "<tr><td>" . $current_match['date'] . "</td><td>" . trim($current_match['text']) . "</td></tr>\n";
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try preg_split with PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE too.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php

```
$text="2012-06-29 App Started
2012-06-30 Login Event";

$data=preg_split("/([0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2})/", $text, 0, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

print_r($data);
```

gives:

Array ( [0] => [1] => 2012-06-29 [2] => App Started [3] => 2012-06-30 [4] => Login Event )

cut the first one off, then all your data is alternative fields.

IF you split by \nDATE this would allow you to have **dates in the text too.**

```
$text="2012-06-29 App Started 2003-20-02
2012-06-30 Login Event";

$data=preg_split("/\\n([0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2})/", "\n".$text, 0, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

Comment: but at least in my example the text could contain numbers LOL

Comment: AND now allows dates in the text, by checking the date at the start of the line

Comment: Add PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY parameter and there will not be an empty element.